# Why doesn't the innerText of an option element show?

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<label name="sel">choose your part</label>
<select id="sel">
<option></option>
<optgroup label="Part 1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Part 2">
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

JS

```
 var a = document.getElementById('sel');
 a.addEventListener('change',call_name,false) ;

 function call_name() {
  alert(this.innerText);
 }
```

In the alert box, it's blank but when I write `this.value` it shows the value of the option. So why does `this.innerText` show an empty string instead of text between them?

Comment: Which `option`? `this` refers to the `select` element, not to any `option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is existing special API for it `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`.

`innerText` is not-standartized feature as said on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

try this:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('sel');
 a.addEventListener('change',call_name,false) ;

 function call_name() {
  alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
 }
```

```html
<label name="sel">choose your part</label>
<select id="sel">
  <option></option>
  <optgroup label="Part 1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Part 2">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```